# Perform an Ajax SPARQL query in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, dbpedia

I'm trying to perform an asynchronous Ajax sparql query on dbpedia with Firefox but I got a weird result and I'm not able to figure out the error. It all seems to work (and it actually works in Chrome, Edge and Internet Explorer) but if it's performed in Firefox the page keeps loading indefinitely after having performed the query and if you refresh the page it shows a blank page. Can somebody explain me why is this happening?
I even tried to use jQuery but with the same result.

```
<script>
    //async request to the url -> print the result
    function httpGetAsync(theUrl) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                //query worked
                document.write(xmlHttp.responseText);
                //xmlHttp.abort();
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    //sparql query
    var query = [
        "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>",
        "SELECT ?album ?artist WHERE {",
        "?album dbo:artist ?artist .",
        "} LIMIT 10"
    ].join(" ");
    //url for the query
    var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    var queryUrl = url + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
    //query call
    httpGetAsync(queryUrl);
</script>
```

With jQuery:

```
<script>
        //async request to the url -> print the result
        function httpGetAsync(theUrl) {
            $.ajax({
                url: theUrl,
                data: {
                    format: 'json'
                },
                error: function() {
                    document.write("error");
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                type: 'GET'
            });
        }
        //sparql query
        var query = [
            "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>",
            "SELECT ?album ?artist WHERE {",
            "?album dbo:artist ?artist .",
            "} LIMIT 10"
        ].join(" ");
        //url for the query
        var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
        var queryUrl = url + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
        //query call
        httpGetAsync(queryUrl);
</script>
```

Comment: Try changing your type value from 'GET' to 'POST' in your ajax call

Comment: Still no luck, it keeps loading for an unknown reason...

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints in your success, error callback functions of your JQuery ajax call?

Comment: Yes, i checked everything and this should be the workflow:
1) ther request is performed
2) the request finished successfully
3) the result is published in the document
Considering that I can see the result all the script is performed.
It should be done but it keeps loading for no reason

Comment: What do you see in the url when the ajax call is made and the browser is stuck in a loading state?

Comment: The browser is stuck after the ajax call has finished
However this is the url of the request: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20SELECT%20%3Falbum%20%3Fartist%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Falbum%20dbo%3Aartist%20%3Fartist%20.%20%7D%20LIMIT%2010

Comment: Maybe add line window.location.href = the original url before your ajax call as the last line in your ajax success and error functions,

Comment: If I add `window.location.href = url` before the ajax request it's going to loop and after the success of the query it shows a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing an element of the dom instead of writing directly into the document solved the problem.

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
```